# XMLHttpRequest Header : Decode Binary Data Upon Server Arrival

Tags: binary, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, content-type, content-disposition

I am building a multipart/form-data httprequest, using Javascript's XMLHttpRequest object. Here are the headers:

```
Accept:  */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length: 38539
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary=CONTENT_BOUNDARY
Cookie: __utma=111872281.167592067.1396133699.1396133699.1396133699.1; PHPSESSID=ea7cfjgi8e29v1bhnrj580vbc2
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:90
Referer: localhost:90/my_secret_referer/no_peeking.php
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
```

I send the request to a PHP document.

In the following snippet one can observe a part of the request body. It details the transmission of binary data in base64 representing an image file that has been selected.

```
--CONTENT_BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images[]"; filename="airplane.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

.../9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/2wBDABkRExYTEBkWFBYcGxkeJT4pJSIiJUw3Oi0...
```

This body part cooperates with the entire request to create **a successful AJAX request** to my server. When the information arrives at the server, I decode the information and do what I may with it.

The segment of this process that I am unsatisfied with is the **manual decoding of the binary data.** One is always able to receive uploaded images in the server as complete, legible image files when using jQuery's *$.ajax()* or [Malsup's *jQuery Form*.](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) I have looked into the format of the two mentioned requests and have found that they too send binary information using a multipart/form-data request. The one difference that I have found which I have not intentionally made is that my request is furnished with a

```
charset: utf8;
```

specification inside of the Content-Type after I send it.

***Can I, and if I can, how can I tell the server to decode the binary information it receives?***

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure but I think only email servers does anything with `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`. I'm curious as to why you're building a multipart/form-data POST body by hand, can't you use FormData/Blob/Typed array?

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your comment. In this project, the user must have the liberty to add and remove selected files of a file input. Within the code, I must: provide a memory of all of the files selected, display previews of the files, and submit them to the server only when the user confirms the submission. I perceived this elasticity of file contents to need a match when submitting a request.

Comment: Okay, but that does not require you to upload them as base64 encoded does it, you can have an array with all your File objects the user selected, add/remove when the user specifies and then upload then with a FormDdata object.